# Laravel using paginate with only selected columns?

Tags: laravel, pagination

I know how to use paginate in laravel ,
but now I want use paginate()
with selected columns only .
this is my pagination code:

```
$data['users']=DB::table('users')->paginate(2);
```

this the sql statement I'm trying to get with paginate.

```
select id,name,username,email,groupName,lastSignIn from users;
```

my laravel code for this select statement:

```
$data['users']=DB::select('select id,name,username,email,groupName,lastSignIn from users;')->paginate(4);
```

but it's not working with me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
// Query\Builder
DB::table('users')
   ->select('id', 'name', 'username', 'email', 'groupName', 'lastSignIn')
   ->paginate(4);
```

And this:

```
DB::select(...);
```

is completely different method of another class (`Connection`).

Comment: can I use it without `select()` like `>get([ 'id', 'name', 'username', 'email', 'groupName', 'lastSignIn' ])` **???**

Comment: @talesid you can, unless you want `paginate()`

Comment: @talesid 1 I suggest being explicit, it will save you and your team some pain. 2 yes, you can specify columns, but not with get and paginate together

Answer (score 33):

You may try this snippet code:

```
$user = User::paginate(5,['id','name','username'.....]);
```

Comment: not working for me Laravel 5.7. it work with ['*'] or ['id'] but not with multiples . Strict mode off. I'm using maria db. here the error:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' ```name```) as aggregate from `companies`' at line 1 (SQL: select count(`id`, ```name```) as aggregate from `companies`)

Comment: are you entering name of columns in array??

Comment: This even works in laravel 8 and its very elegant.