# How to paginate a specific column in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I want to paginate just the images not the whole model

Here are the codes from the **create_galleries_table.php** :

```
 Schema::create('galleries', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->id();
     $table->timestamps();
     $table->string('title');
     $table->string('images');
 });
```

**GalleriesController.php** :

```
public function index()
{
   $galleries = Gallery::all();
   return view('gallery.index', compact('galleries'));
}
```

**index.blade.php** :

```
@foreach ($galleries as $gallery)
  <div>
     <h1>{{$gallery->title}}</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
     <img src="{{$gallery->images}}">
  </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel using paginate with only selected columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949037/laravel-using-paginate-with-only-selected-columns)

Comment: @MaxiGui No I tried that, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`paginate()` method takes columns as second parameter

```
public function index()
{
   $galleries = Gallery::paginate(20,['images']);
   return view('gallery.index', compact('galleries'));
}
```

Comment: That still paginates the whole Gallery table, and besides it only shows the images not the title

Answer (score 0):

in the controller

```
public function index()
{
   $galleries = Gallery::paginate(5);
   return view('gallery.index', compact('galleries'));
}
```

in the blade add links

```
@if(count($galleries) > 0)
      <div>{{ $galleries->links() }}</div>
@endif
```

Comment: That will also paginate the whole table, not only the "images" column

Comment: you can user $galleries = Gallery::pluck('images')->paginate(5);

Comment: this error shows `Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::paginate does not exist.`